# how to use node.js parse an array by using Promise or Generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, es6-promise

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
var b = []

a.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(it) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      b.push(it)
    }, 1000);
  })
})

console.log(b);
```

use Promise Or Generate?
I tried, but b = [],
not b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
var url = 'http://www.imooc.com/learn/348'
function getLinks(url){
  var link_arry = []
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body)
    var chapters = $('.chapter')
    var courseName = $('.path').find('span').text()

    chapters.each(function (item) {
      var chapter = $(this)
      var chapterTitle = chapter.find('strong').text()
      
      var videos = chapter.find('li')
      videos.each(function (item) {
        var video = $(this).find('.studyvideo')
        var videoTitle = video.text().trim().replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')
        var id = video.attr('href').split('video/')[1]

        link_arry.push(id)
      })
    })
  })
  return link_arry
}
```

use request to get a web page which contains a courese,some chapters,some sectinos
when i use return link_arry, always get an empty array
so ...

want the link_arry

Comment: why should `b` be non-empty? you delay all those calls by 1 second, so `console.log(b)` will execute BEFORE any of those timeouts has had a chance to actually time out.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you're just wanting to merge the arrays, why have the timeout at all? And if you're demoing some more complex need, what is that need?

Comment: for some reason i'm not only want to merge the arrarys，update some detials

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the use of the `setTimeout`, nevermind I give you a solution using Promises

```
var a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var b = [];

var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var totalLength = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], a).length;

     a.forEach(function(item) {
        item.forEach(function(it) {
           setTimeout(function () {
              b.push(it);
              if(b.length === totalLength) resolve();
            }, 1000);
         })
     });
});

promise.then(function() {
   console.log(b);
});
```

You can also use `generator` to achieve your task :

```
function getAllValues() {
    var result = [];
    var totalLength = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], a).length;

    a.forEach(function(item) {
        item.forEach(function(it) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                result.push(it);
                if(result.length == totalLength) gen.next(result);
            }, 1000);
        })
    });
}

function *generator() {
    b = yield getAllValues();
    console.log(b);
}

var gen = generator();
//start the generator
gen.next();
```

Comment: thank you , i have watch some docs , often see they use generator and yield to wait the function run out , can here use that way, this also i used setTimeout

Comment: @TanLing I just edited my post using generator to accomplish the same thing